# Linq group by a nullable timestamp (use only date part) and count

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I am trying to convert this SQL to linq syntax, but I'm having some difficulties at that.

```
SELECT trans_date, count(*) FROM table1
GROUP BY trans_date
```

Result
01-01-2001 | 12
03-01-2001 | 45

```
var q = from a in table1
let dt = q.trans_date.value
group q by new {y = dt.Year.ToString(), m = dt.Month.ToString(), d = dt.Day.toString()}
into g
select new { int NumOf = g.Count(), DateTime TransDate = DateTime.Parse(g.Key.y + g.key.m + g.Key.d)}
```

This last "version" with the DateTime.Parse gives me a runtime error.

How to handle that the q.trans_date is a nullable DateTime and getting my resultset??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one thing, you're not getting a *runtime* error with that code - you'll be getting a *compile-time* error as your code isn't valid C#.

Try this:

```
var q = from a in table1
        group a by a.trans_date.value.Date into g
        select new {
            Count = g.Count(),
            TransDate = g.Key
        };
```

Comment: Typo on your group by variable

Comment: @Aducci: Where? I was just going by the original code. Do you mean `value` should be `Value`? Could be - but as I say, I was following the code in the question.

Comment: group **a** by **a**.trans_date.value.Date

Comment: also replace `group a by a.trans_date.value.Date into g` by `group a by a.trans_date into g` it should work perfectly (g.Key should be null if trans_date is null).